# Atmel AVR Studio 6 using Arduino Uno (ATmega328p) and FreeRTOS

Tags: avr, atmega, freertos, avrdude, atmelstudio

Hey there all,

I want to begin working with freeRTOS using my Arduino Uno which uses the ATmega328p on Atmel AVR Studio 6.

I am working on windows 7.

I went into this tutorial:

http://www.jayconsystems.com/tutorial/atmerpt1/

which describes how to install and prepare the Atmel AVR Studio 6 to work with ATmega328p.

I failed to understand what should I do in step 5A , which tells to do the following:

Go to Tools -> External Tools...
Create the new tool with these settings:

Title: Serial Program

Command: C:\arduino-1.0.1\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avrdude.exe

(Change that to match your arduino installation folder and locate avrdude.exe)

-CC:\arduino-1.0.1\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf -patmega328p -carduino -P\.\COM3 -b57600 -Uflash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex":i    **// ***

NOTE: I do have the avrdude.exe installed on my computer at this location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avrdude.exe

So my questions are:

1) On the line ***** , what does -CC mean, does it needs to be within the arguments or the initial directory (within the External Tools dialog box)?

2) As it is mentioned , the path to the avrdude.conf  (indeed in my case) goes through the X86 folder , so how does the line I need to enter there should be (cause it is mentioned there something about double quotes)?

3) After I will solve all of these problems how/where/does AVR Studio 6 has a "simple generic template" project to get started with freeRTOS ?

I ran into this tutorial (which uses different board) , can I "follow" it although I am using another board (my ATmega328p)?

Thanks allot in advance,

Guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `-C` is an option to the avrdude executable to specify the configuration file. The second C is part of the filename: `C:\`.

2) If the path to the configuration file has a space in the name, then it will get messed up when passed as an option to avrdude.exe. (The path will end with the space, and the rest will be junk that causes the command to fail.)

To get around spaces in a string, surround the string with quotes.

`-C"C:\a directory with   spaces\a filename with spaces in it.conf"`

3) is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow (recommending a tool or resource.)

Comment: Thanks allot for your explantion , yet I  faiiled to activate the avrdude from the avr studio - after I go to extranl tools -> serial program (the name I gave it) a window (somekind of a prompt) opens and then immidiatley closes.

Comment: An error is occurring to close the window. Look around for a log file. Also, check out the avrdude options documentation to make sure you are using the correct options for your board. Try running avrdude in a console window from Windows first to get the options right. That should keep the window open to see what the error is.